# Azure Resorce Explorer - Where to see Locks?

Tags: azure

Suppose I set a Lock on some Azure resource (e.g. on Resource Group). Then I want to see JSON document in Azure Resource Explorer that corresponds to the created Lock. I can see the resource object document but the Lock is not shown there.

Comment: Any update? If you think it makes sense, could you accept it?

Comment: @ Joy Wang I sent this question / feature request to Microsoft. When they answer, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use powershell to see it.

```
Get-AzResourceLock -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

For more details about azure cli or rest api, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources).

Comment: Absolutely. I can do it with CLI as well, `az lock show`.  The question is about Resource Explorer as a tool.

Comment: @user2341923 Not all the resources will disappear in the resource explorer, I don't think you can see `Microsoft.Authorization/locks` in it.

Comment: @user2341923 The explorer essentially calls the rest api, if you are not insisting on using it, just call the rest api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/managementlocks

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain those are not exposed under resource explorer. since the `Microsoft.Authorization` provider is not even listed in there

you could use any other means to retrieve those